# How to preload local javascript everytime a new tab or page is opened?

Tags: javascript

I would like to autoload a local javascript file, everytime a new page/tab is opened in a browser. I tried the bookmarklet approach, but it gets tiresome as the button needs to be pressed everytime a new page/tab is opened. Chrome extensions also seem to work along the same lines (where you have to press an icon to run the js). Googling for javascript and preload seems to return everything except what I am looking for.

Is there a browser indepent way of autoloading (no user action required) a local js file? If not, any browser specific info to do this would be appreciated (even if they mean reducing security by turning off required options). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748).